# How to generate PDF in django which in-turn has another PDF?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, reportlab, xhtml2pdf

I am using xhtml2pdf for generating pdf in django. When I render images in the HTML am able to generate PDF but I dont understand how can I render another PDF while creating my PDF.(one thought i got is to convert the PDF(to be rendered) to image using django filter but am not sure how to achieve it)

Comment: What do you mean by this: "render another PDF while creating my PDF"?

Comment: Am creating a PDF with name new.pdf , the HTML which will be converted into new.pdf in turn has another pdf embedded in it(in html).

Comment: Why not just fetch the embedded PDF then?

Comment: When embedded it is not displaying blank in that place.